# How to toggle class of an element with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i need to toggle some css effect when one of the images of the list is clicked (but only in the image that was clicked). I did this but is not working.

I'm trying to do it using "classList.toggle('selected')", but the css doesn't change. I don't know if there is some way to do it with 'useState'.

I'm learning reactjs, i hope someone can help.

REACTJS

```
const Photos = () =>{

  const[mainPhoto, setMainPhoto] = useState(Barco)

  const changePhoto = (element) => {
    setMainPhoto(element.target.src)
    let target = element.currentTarget;
    target.classList.toggle('selected')
  }

  return(
      <section className={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
          <img src={mainPhoto}/>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
          <div className={styles.infoArea}>
            <h1>LOren </h1>
            <p className={styles.resume}>LOren</p>
            <p className={styles.about}>LOren LOren LOren LOrenLOrenLOrenLOren LOrenLOren LOren LOren LOren LOrenLOren
            LOren LOrens
            </p>
            <h2>Fotografia:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>User 01</li>
              <li>User 02</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.photoArea}>
            <div>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Surf}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
              <img onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e)} src={Barco}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  )
}

export default Photos
```

SCSS

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  object-fit: cover;

  &:hover {
    filter: blur(1px);
  }

  &.selected {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely use and change state to cause changes to the DOM. In React, never use native DOM methods like `classList.toggle`.

For this case, use a numeric index state of the index of the selected image. First have an array of srcs, eg

```
const srcs = [Surf, Barco, ...]
```

Then map over them, with a click handler that uses the iteration index to decide how to change the selected index in state:

```
const [indexSelected, setIndexSelected] = useState(-1);
const handleClick = i => () => {
  setIndexSelected(i === indexSelected ? -1 : indexSelected);
};
// ...
  <div className={styles.photoArea}>
    <div>
      {
        srcs.map((src, i) => <img
          onClick={handleClick(i)}
          className={i === indexSelected ? 'selected' : ''}
          src={src}
        />)
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I tried your code but it did'nt work. Nice to know that i  should do it with "state".... So, i will try to do something.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Can you explain what the problem you encounter is?

Comment: I had to make some changes to make it work. But your answer helped me a lot. I will post here what i did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by doing some changes.

REACT

```
const Photos = () =>{

  const[mainPhoto, setMainPhoto] = useState(Barco)
  const[selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

  const changePhoto = (element, index) => {
    setMainPhoto(element.target.src)
    setSelected(index)
  }

  const images = [Barco, Surf]

  return(
      <section className={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
          <img src={mainPhoto}/>
          <button className={styles.previous} >
            <GrPrevious size={24} />
          </button>
          <button className={styles.next}>
            <GrNext size={24}/>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.titleContainer}>
          <div className={styles.infoArea}>
            <h1>LOren </h1>
            <p className={styles.resume}>LOren</p>
            <p className={styles.about}>LOren LOren LOren LOrenLOrenLOrenLOren LOrenLOren LOren LOren LOren LOrenLOren
            LOren LOrens
            </p>
            <h2>Fotografia:</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Guilherme Donada</li>
              <li>Guilherme Do nada</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.photoArea}>
            <div>
            {images.map((image,index) => (              
              <img 
                key={index}
                onClick={ (e) => changePhoto(e, index)}  
                src={image} 
                className={ index == selected ? styles.selected : '' }
              />
            ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  )
}

export default Photos
```